# Проблемы с загрузкой координат границ регионов при помощи yandex map

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь написать простую программу, которая  при нажатии добавляла маркер на карту и выводила регионы России. Но у меня проблема, он постоянно выводит такую ошибку.

```
"перехвачена ошибка типа: не удается прочитать свойства undefined (чтение 'load')"
```

ссылаюсь на строчку

```
 ".borders.load('RU'
```

Я уже все перепробовал.

Например вызывал так:

```
ymaps.current.load('RU', {
    language: 'ru', // language for region names
  }).then(function (geojson) {
        var regions = promise.resolve(ymaps.geoQuery(geojson));
        regions.Add a map(mapRef);
       }) .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
});
```

```
const YMap = () => {
    const ymaps = React.useRef(null);
    const placemarkRef = React.useRef(null);
    const mapRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [address, SetAddress] = React.useState("");

    const createPlacemark = (coords) => {
        return new ymaps.current.Placemark(
           coords,{
                iconCaption: "loading.."
            },
            {
                preset: "islands#violetDotIconWithCaption",
                draggable: true
            }
        );

    };

   
    const getAddress = (coords) => {
        placemarkRef.current.properties.set("iconCaption", "loading..");
        ymaps.current.geocode(coords).then((res) => {
            const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            console.log(res)
            const newAddress = [
                firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length
                    ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities()
                    : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
            ]
                .filter(Boolean)
                .join(", ");
            SetAddress(newAddress);
            placemarkRef.current.properties.set({
                iconCaption: newAddress,
                balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
            });

ymaps.borders.load('RU', {
    lang: 'ru', // язык для названий регионов
}).then(function (geojson) {
    const regionName = 'Москва'; // название региона
    const region = ymaps.geoQuery(geojson)
        .search('properties.name == $name', { name: regionName })
        .get(0);
    const regionBounds = region.geometry.getBounds();
    console.log(`Границы региона "${regionName}": ${regionBounds}`);
});

        })
    const onMapClick = (e) => {
        const coords = e.get("coords");
        if (placemarkRef.current) {
            placemarkRef.current.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
        } else {
            placemarkRef.current = createPlacemark(coords);            
            mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(placemarkRef.current);
            placemarkRef.current.events.add("dragend", function () {
                getAddress(placemarkRef.current.geometry.getCoordinates());
            });
        }
        getAddress(coords);
    };

    return (    
        <YMaps query={{ 
                        // load: "package.full" , 
                        apikey: "" }}>
            <Map defaultState={{
                    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                    zoom: 9
                }} 
                modules={["control.ZoomControl", "control.FullscreenControl","Placemark", "geocode", "geoObject.addon.balloon"]}
                style={{
                    flex: 2,
                    height: "calc(100vh - 57px)"
                }}
                onClick={onMapClick}    
                instanceRef={mapRef}
                onLoad={(ympasInstance) => (ymaps.current = ympasInstance)}
                state={mapState}
            >
            </Map>
        </YMaps>
    )
}
export default YMap;
```

Comment: Попробуй ymaps.current.borders.load(). Инстанс у тебя ведь в ymaps.current.
Хотя не очень понимаю, зачем вообще нужна везде прокладка current.

Comment: @ВикторКарев Выдает тужу ошибку.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')

Comment: А, у тебя же не все модули загружаются, а по списку. Попробуй добавить модуль Borders. Правда, не уверен, что нужен именно такой. Список модулей нужно откуда-то взять.

Comment: @ВикторКарев , да вы совершенно были правы. Ошибка была в этом.